# как сделать объект в объекте

Tags: javascript

```
"{"a":{"b":{"c":{}}}}"
```

как реализовать функцию, которая будет выводить возвращать вот такой объект. Пробовал через Object.create и мозг себе сломал.

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {"a":{"b":{"c":{}}}}
console.log(obj)
```

выводит именно этот объект

Answer (score 0):

Пойдет так?

```js
let object = {a:{b:{c:{}}}};

let object1 = {};

object1.a = {};

object1.a.b = {};

object1.a.b.c = {};

console.log(object);
console.log(object1);
```